# CSS: draw lines between flexboxes

Tags: css, flexbox

I successfully created a nested flexbox layout for my pedigree. But how do I draw lines inbetween? This is possible using CSS3, see http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree But this example doesn't explain anything and I cannot get it to work with my code.

I am not sure if my approach makes sense: it's flexbox columns inside flex-items that are aligned in a row.

```css
pedigree {
  border: 1px solid green;

  /* flex container */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

individual:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #FFE6E6;
}

individual {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #E6E6FF;

  /* flex item */
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: stretch;
  -ms-flex-item-align: stretch;
  align-self: stretch; 
}

individual:before, .individual:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
individual:after{
    right: auto; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


gen0, gen1, gen2, gen3 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  
  /* flex item */
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: stretch;
  
  /* flex container */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-around; 
}

ind_name, ind_birth, ind_marriage, ind_death {
  border:none;
  display:block;
}

ind_name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ind_birth:before {
  content: "* ";
}

ind_marriage:before {
  content: "oo ";
}

ind_death:before {
  content: "+ ";
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <pedigree>
    <gen0>
      <individual>
        <ind_num>1</ind_num>
        <ind_name>Individual</ind_name>
        <ind_birth>19 Nov</ind_birth>
      </individual>
    </gen0>
    <gen1>
      <individual>
        <ind_num>2</ind_num>
        <ind_name>Father</ind_name>
        <ind_birth>1 Mar</ind_birth>
      </individual>
      <individual>
        <ind_num>3</ind_num>
        <ind_name>Mother</ind_name>
        <ind_birth>10 Sep</ind_birth>
      </individual>
    </gen1>
    <gen2>
      <individual>
        <ind_num>4</ind_num>
        <ind_name>Grandfather</ind_name>
        <ind_birth>1 Nov</ind_birth>
      </individual>
      <individual>
        <ind_num>5</ind_num>
        <ind_name>Grandmother</ind_name>
        <ind_birth>9 Feb</ind_birth>
      </individual>
      <individual>
        <ind_num>6</ind_num>
        <ind_name>Grandfather</ind_name>
        <ind_birth>5 Jan</ind_birth>
      </individual>
      <individual>
        <ind_num>7</ind_num>
        <ind_name>Grandmother</ind_name>
        <ind_birth>15 Nov</ind_birth>
      </individual>
    </gen2>
  </pedigree>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the right approach here would be to use svg instead of the flexbox items you are using. That still gives you a lot of control on the display (via CSS) and animations/events, while allowing you indeed to draw the lines. Accessibility might be more complex to get right, though.

Comment: OP could look at using d3.js for drawing family trees.